# Warning message when patch is applied?

Tags: version-control

I applied a patch and I get a Warinig message.

Then it states that the patch was applied cleanly.

Can I trust this?

This is the complete code:

```
example@d565:~/www$ git apply -v SA-CORE-2014-005-D7.patch
Checking patch includes/database/database.inc...
warning: includes/database/database.inc has type 100755, expected 100644
Hunk #1 succeeded at 733 (offset -3 lines).
Applied patch includes/database/database.inc cleanly.
example@d565:~/www$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> warning: includes/database/database.inc has type 100755, expected 100644

You can trust that the file has been applied successfully, but not that the file was in the expected state to begin with.

`755` and `644` refering to [numeric notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation) of unix-system file permissions.

What the warning says is that the patch lists the file as being not executable, but it found the file to be executable.
This had no effect on applying the contents of the patch to the file though.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand that the patch is applied. But then, should I change the file permission to 644?

Comment: Well there's no point in having any of Drupal's php files executable, 644 would normally be very highest permission that makes sense, and lower would be better. The only php file that should normally be executable is one that starts drush up.

Comment: thanks, I didn't change the permission for this file though.